# Fused disconnect fuse size question

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I am installing a steam generator. The unit draws 42 amps. I have a two pole 50 amp breaker at the service box per the instruction manual. Per the manual, The unit needs a fused disconnect at the generator. I have a two fuse 60 amp disconnect requiring 2 fuses. My question is what size fuses do I need?

Comment: 10% above the consumption

Comment: I am confused by the terminology.  I assume that the 2 fuses on the two wires (an not in parallel or series)

Comment: The unit is rated as consuming  42 A. 110% of 42 is 46.2.  But I'm not certain whether that gets rounded down or up. One fuse goes in each hot leg, assuming two-phase power, since 42 A runs through both and you want to blow if current across either goes higher than that 10% buffer. I think.

Comment: I don't where 10% comes from. The general rule for wire and breaker sizing is 25% - e.g., a 12A continuous load gets a 15A breaker and 14 AWG wire, 16A -> 20A/12 AWG, 24A -> 30A/10 AWG, etc. And fuses can be used instead of breakers. But whether the rules vary for "disconnects" and whether this particular equipment has any specifics, I don't know. 42A x 1.25 = 52.5 which could argue for a 60A disconnect. **What does the manual say?**